# How to ignore first 4 and output rest after then values using foreach PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables, foreach

The first part of the script getting first 4 values from the array and outputs results as a list. The second part of the script should get the rest of the values such as 5, 6 .. 10, etc if any and place them all in one div, but at the moment my second part of the script still grabs all of the values of the array starting from the first.

Here is my script

```
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($value as $category_topic)
    if(++$counter <= 4){
   $template_image = '<img src="'.$image_path.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['templateImage'].'" width="'.$category_topic['templimgwidth'].'" height="'.$category_topic['templimgheight'].'" alt="'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'" title="'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'">';
    $template_link ='<a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'">'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'</a>';
    print<<<END

      <li>
       <ul>
        <li>{$template_image}</li>
        <li class="bot_link">{$template_link}</li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    END;
    }
    print <<<END

    </ul>
    <div>

    END;
    foreach ($value as $category_topic)
    if(++$counter > 4){
    $template_link[++$counter] ='<a href="'.DST.$category_topic['ImagePath'].DS.$category_topic['referring_url'].'">'.$category_topic['templateTitle'].'</a>';
    print<<<END

    {$template_link}
    END;
    }
    print <<<END

    </div>
    </div>

    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `for` as suggested, but here is an alternate:

```
foreach(array_slice($value, 0, 4) as $category_topic) {
    //...this is the first 4
}

//...

foreach(array_slice($value, 4) as $category_topic) {
    //...this is 5 to the end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of a `for` instead of a `foreach`

```
for($i = 4; $i < count($value); $i++)
{
  // your code...... 
}
```

**EDIT :**

For 1st part.

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
//your code...
}
```

For 2nd part.

```
for($i=4;$i<count($value);$i++)
{
//your code...
}
```

Comment: THanks, but in which part of the script, top or bottom?

Comment: @AlexB Why not both? (or let me rephrase: every part where you want to start at a specified index)